# TCP socket data in-consistency in linux

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, wxwidgets, tcpclient

I need some information regarding the following.

I am creating server and client for tracing the data. The data sent from the client is displayed on the GUI by wxWidgets. Here is my problem.

I have two tracing clients, each client sending the data of 100 messages in 0.9 microseconds. My problem is that the data received at the server is not in order.

```
Example:
Actual data:

data from client 1
data from client 1
data from client 1
data from client 2
data from client 1
data from client 1
data from client 1
data from client 2
data from client 1
data from client 1
data from client 2

Received data on server side:
data from client 2
data from client 2
data from client 1
data from client 1
data from client 1
data from client 2
data from client 1
data from client 1
data from client 1
```

Question:

How to resolve this data mismatch problem? I am using TCP socket. All the code's are written in CPP.

John

Comment: You basically have to handle that at the application level. A simple way that might work would be to synchronize your hosts to the same clock and add a timestamp field to the messages sent, then at the server order the messages received based on their timestamp, then display them.

Comment: How do you know it's not received in order? Network time is a non-trivial problem. How do you know it wasn't just *printed* in the wrong order?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can guarantee data sync between two unrelated TCP clients on different hosts. TCP only guarantees order of data in a connection.

One way to guarantee this may be, is to have a token passed from the server to the client whenever client wants to send some data. The token may be assumed to be 'used' when the client has done sending data.

1. Client : Request token for data to be sent
2. Server: Allocates token to client
3. Client sends data and signals end of data
4. Server assumes token expired for client and is free to allocate to another.

   Of course, the client shouldn't send any data after end of data or when token is not available with it.